# Can't compare attribute to a number. Error: "not supported between instances of 'AnsibleUnsafeText' and 'int'"

Tags: ansible, jinja2

```
- getent:
    database: passwd
- debug: 
    var: getent_passwd | dict2items | selectattr('value.1', '>=', 1000) | map(attribute='key') | list
```

And output is

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on 
({{getent_passwd | dict2items | selectattr('value.1', '>=', 1000) | map(attribute='key') | list}}): 
'>=' not supported between instances of 'AnsibleUnsafeText' and 'int'"}
```

How can I change 'value.1' to integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: *"**How can I change `value.1` to an integer?**"*

A: Use [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) function [to_number](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#to-number). For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: getent_passwd|
             dict2items|
             json_query('[?to_number(value[1]) >= `1000`].key')
```

---

Q: *"**How can I change `1000` into a variable?**"*

A: The substitution should be converted to a number too. It's a good idea to declare the `query` separately. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        myusers: "{{ getent_passwd|dict2items|json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        myuid: 1000
        query: "[?to_number(value[1]) >= to_number('{{ myuid }}')].key"
```

---

Q: *"**How can I add more conditions into json_query function? Like `selectattr('value.5', 'ne', '/sbin/nologin')`.**"*

A: Use [pipe](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#pipe-expressions) or [and-expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#grammar). For example

```yaml
    - getent:
        database: passwd
    - set_fact:
        myusers: "{{ getent_passwd|dict2items|json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        myuid: 1000
        myshell: /usr/sbin/nologin
        query: "[?to_number(value[1]) >= to_number('{{ myuid }}')] |
                [?value[5] == '{{ myshell }}'].{user: key, uid: value[1], shell: value[5]}"
    - debug:
        var: myusers
```

give

```yaml
    "myusers": [
        {
            "user": "libvirt-qemu", 
            "shell": "/usr/sbin/nologin", 
            "uid": "64055"
        }, 
        {
            "user": "nobody", 
            "shell": "/usr/sbin/nologin", 
            "uid": "65534"
        }
    ]
```

Fit the variables and the [Comparison Operator](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#comparison-operators) to your needs.

The pipe in json_query might be considered an anti-pattern. Therefore [and-expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#grammar) should be used instead of the pipe. For example

```yaml
  query: "[?(to_number(value[1]) >= to_number('{{ myuid }}')) &&
            (value[5] == '{{ myshell }}')].{user: key, uid: value[1], shell: value[5]}"
```

Comment: Thank you, it's work! but how can I add more condition into json_query function? Like "selectattr('value.5', 'ne', '/sbin/nologin')". Can you give me a solution please..

Comment: And how can I change `1000` in to variable.

Comment: Open a new question if you have other issues.