# How to register and capture only the output that meets a failed condition criteria in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to set up a playbook as follows where I need to send an email notification when my task fails. The alert with email notification as such works as expected, however I am unable to capture the output just for the failed conditions and currently the way I am registering gives me all results including the variables (file paths in this example) where the condition does not fail.

```
---

- hosts: test-box

  tasks:
    - name: alert on failure
      block:
          - name: generate a list of desired file paths 
            find:
                    paths: /base/sdir
                    recurse: yes
                    file_type: file
                    patterns: "abrn.*.dat"
                    use_regex: yes
            register: file_paths

 
          - name: check if file stopped updating 
            vars:
                  msg: |
                          "{{ item }}"
                          "{{ ansible_date_time.epoch }}"
                          "{{ item.stat.mtime|int }}" 
                          "{{ ( (ansible_date_time.epoch|int - item.stat.mtime|int) / 60 ) | int }} min"
            with_items: "{{ ts.results }}"

            fail:
                  msg: | 
                          "{{ msg.split('\n') }}" 
            register: failed_items    ### -> HOW TO REGISTER ONLY THE FILE PATHS (RESULTS) WHERE THIS FAIL CONDITION IS MET?? 
            when: ( (ansible_date_time.epoch|int - item.stat.mtime|int) / 60 ) | int > 2 


      rescue:
          - name: email notification  
            mail:
              host: localhost
              port: 25
              from: A
              to: B
              subject: TASK FAILED
              body: |
                   Failed subdirs: {{ failed_items }}  ## This gives me all results including those where the failed condition is not met
            delegate_to: localhost

...
```

In the body of the email, I want to capture only the file paths where the mtime condition is met but currently I get all file paths.

Any suggestions on how I can filter to capture the output only for matching condition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `set_fact`, this way you will assign a list variable only if your `when` condition is true.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  vars:
    path: "{{ '%s/bin' | format(lookup('env', 'HOME')) }}"
    time: "{{ 2 * 60 }}" # 2 mins
  tasks:
    - name: Find files in a defined path
      find:
        paths: "{{ path }}"
      register: _result
    - name: Add files not modified for longer time than defined to list
      set_fact:
        stale_files: "{{ stale_files | default([]) + [item.path] }}"
      loop: "{{ _result.files }}"
      when: ((ansible_date_time.epoch | float) - item.mtime) > (time | float)
    - name: Show stale files
      debug:
        msg: "{{ stale_files }}"
```

Well you could use also another approach, ie. make loop with filtering (for me `selectattr` filter did not work with `lt` test, thus `json_query` filter should work, see [Can't compare attribute to a number. Error: "not supported between instances of 'AnsibleUnsafeText' and 'int'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751070/cant-compare-attribute-to-a-number-error-not-supported-between-instances-of)).

Comment: This way it does not work for me for some reason: Any other working example?                                                                        
```          - set_fact: failedItems="{{all_items}}"
            when: all_items.changed
```